# Couchbase server always pending

Tags: couchbase, server

i've got a problem setting up my couchbase server on my new macbook.
I have installed Couchbase 3.0.1 and i am running OS X 10.10

I can login to the webconsole. But there it always tells me my server on 127.0.0.1 is down/pending. I can't get it to run properly.

I already checked the log, but can't get any idea out of it.

One error which appears again and again:

```
[stats:error,2014-10-31T10:06:11.844,ns_1@127.0.0.1:<0.2019.0>:stats_collector:handle_info:124]Exception in stats collector: {exit,
       {{bad_return_value,
           {stop,{error,couldnt_connect_to_memcached}}},
               {gen_server,call,
                   ['ns_memcached-obd_data',
                     {stats,<<>>},
                        180000]}},
                           [{gen_server,call,3,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,188}]},
                            {ns_memcached,do_call,3,
                             [{file,"src/ns_memcached.erl"},{line,1401}]},
                            {stats_collector,grab_all_stats,1,
                             [{file,"src/stats_collector.erl"},{line,84}]},
                            {stats_collector,handle_info,2,
                             [{file,"src/stats_collector.erl"},
                              {line,116}]},
                            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,604}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
```

Anyone an idea how to solve my problem and get the server started?
Or is there any common known problem already?

Comment: did you figure out why, it is 2018 and i am still in same boat